# Checking the contents of the record before it is shown to listview using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I would like to display a gray star image if column `"status"==0` and display a golden star if column `"status"==1`. My code can display the record to `listview`, but without checking the "status" column first:

```
public void loadPertanyaan(){
        Cursor soal = DBAdapter.fetchSemuaSoal();
        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_SOAL_PERTANYAAN};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.txt_PilihSoal_Pertanyaan};
        SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, soal, from, to);
        setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

Then I add code to check `status` column using `moveToNext()` after `setListAdapter(dataAdapter)`. But the application always force stopped, code to check "answered" column below  -

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBintang);
    while(soal.moveToNext()){
        if(soal.getInt(soal.getColumnIndex("status"))==1)
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bintang_mas);
        else
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bintang_abu);
    }
```

How can I check `"status"` column before displaying to `ListView`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agi, You need a good tutorial like link [Populating a ListView with a CursorAdapter](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) . Look at code `bindView` similar to `getView` method, mentioned in a previous answer. getView is less intensive so it may be good enough for you.

Look at LinearLayout resource XML. In it, there are 2 TextView elements. Instead, I think you need more columns in your ListView, like TextView, popular Checkbox, and an image for the star (bintang).

The code is different than your thoughts in design. It gets and displays **data in** **virtual** mode, and you can check the data by the `position` or `Cursor` parameter.

Good luck and tell me how it goes for you...

Comment: I know you're at Bandung and I came from Jakarta, now in LA. There is a 15-hour time difference between us.  Selamat and semoga untung.

Comment: Terima kasih banyak om @The Original Android, referensinya berhasil saya bisa menampilkan bintang abu - abu ketika `status`nya masih 0 dan bintang mas ketika `status`nya sudah menjadi 1. Terima kasih banyak. saya berharap kita bisa berjumpa nanti, di Bandung sekarang tengah malam. Saya mengerjakan tugas sambil begadang hahaha

Comment: Thank you Mr @The Original Android, your reference is great, i can shown gray star if `status` == 0 and shown gold star if `status` == 1.

Comment: Hello Agi, Kalau suka jawabanku, pilih best answer. Terserah kamu.

Comment: how to vote your answer Mr? I wanna give you 2 thumbs

Comment: Agi,  click on the up-arrow on the left of my posted answer, and only you can choose for Best since you posted the question. You can only click once, no more. Thanks for asking.

Comment: bad. my reputation is not enough , at least I must have 15 reputation

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. You will make 15 rep soon and don't forget me. Just ask another question or solve one. Selamat

Comment: Hi Agi, I checked the web;s tutorial @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour, and you can still pick my answer to be best or correct answer by clicking on the checkmark icon, left of the posted answer.

Comment: I not seen your answer at [stackoverflow/tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) . May i ask your facebook account address? I wanna ask many thing about Android, i can't bring our conversation to char feature at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site. Thank you. Mr @The Original Android.

Comment: Agi, You misunderstood me. The Stackoverflow tour is a guide for you to understand how to use this site in a nice and efficient manner. What I meant is that you can click on the check icon besides this posted answer, if you think it is the best correct answer. You can email me questions and post your questions to Stackoverflow also, do both.